# No out of pod networking on EKS cluster

Tags: networking, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have an EKS cluster(1.24) launched with Terraform's AWS EKS module. System generated security groups. Private or public subnets.

Cluster Inbound:
[image: Cluster Inbound Security Group Ports]

Node Inbound:
[image: Node Level Ingress Security Group Ports]

Node Outbound:
[image: Node Level Egress Security Group Ports]

The cluster has 1 node and the backplane. It comes online the node connects and is in a ready state. Although coredns is mega sad as it can't fetch the version from the Cluster API.

When it comes online there is no sign of issue but it wont connect to the control plane API via the local loop back. And it has no internet connectivity.

```
./kubectl run -i --tty --rm debug --image=busybox -- sh
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
/ #  wget $KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_ADDR:$KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT/version
Connecting to 172.20.0.1:443 (172.20.0.1:443)
wget: can't connect to remote host (172.20.0.1): Connection timed out

/ # nc gooogle.com
nc: bad address 'gooogle.com'
```

I've checked the NACL against another account where its working and it looks okay to me. I've tried it with and without the VPC CNI.

At node level, the node can connect to the internet, and pull images. What am I missing at pod level, why can't it connect to the API and why can't it connect to the internet?

Answer (score 0):

Someone who comes up with our custom AMI images decided to set
`sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward` to 0 which blocked all network traffic